# monero-nodejs Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:18082

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

Right now I am using github.com/PsychicCat/monero-nodejs and am getting the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:18082 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete (node:net:1138:16) {
   errno: -111,
   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: '127.0.0.1',
   port: 18082
}
```

Anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect to the host and port you are using for `monero-wallet-rpc`. Port 18082 is the default `monerod` zmq port, so if you want to use that port for the wallet RPC, you have to either disable zmq in `monerod` or tell `monerod` to use a different zmq port.